# How to get checkout state of stripe in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I am trying to make subscribed to an active plan.
so first I'd like to get success state of stripe checkout in Nuxt.js.
And I am using vue-stripe module.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      this.pk = "pk_test_5*******************************************";
      return {
        lineItems: [
            {
            price: 'price_**************Im', // The id of the one-time price you created in your Stripe dashboard
            quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        successUrl: 'https://main.*********.com/home',
        cancelUrl: 'https://main.*********.com/pricing',
      };
    },
    methods: {
        checkout () {
            this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
        }        
    },
  };
  </script>
```

And I'd like to save success state in amplify.
what is the best way?

I am trying to get success of stripe checkout in Nuxt.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripe recommendation is to utilise [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) for any payment/order reconciliation. Webhooks allow you to perform asynchronous actions, like updating a database, when receiving events that are fired from your Stripe account according to activity (like a new payment, for example).

In the specific case of Checkout, a `checkout.session.completed` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) will be fired when your customers successful pay on the hosted payment page. There's documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) on how to implement a webhook handler for those events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Amplify and Nuxt.js. But I cannot get checkout state.
Should I create webhook on stripe for getting checkout state?